# Access to arrays with different types of variables (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I defined this array.

```
val arr = arrayOf("A", "B", 12.3, 45.67)
```

And I want load this code.

```
if(arr[2] < 40) {
  // ... 
}
```

Error occurs at '<'.
Error Message is...

Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun String.compareTo(other: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): Int defined in kotlin.text

So, I changed conditional statements

```
if(arr[2]?.toString()?.toDouble() !!< 40)
```

Can I write the code more simply than this?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that the array you defined, arr, is of type Array<Any>. This is because it contains both String and Double values. So, when you try to compare arr[2] to 40 using the < operator, the compiler doesn't know how to handle it, as arr[2] is inferred to be of type Any. You would need to check the type at runtime and then perform the comparison like "if (arr[2] is Double && arr[2] as Double < 40)"

Comment: Why do you store items of different types in the first place? What is your use case? If indexes are meaningful, so e.g. index `2` means a very specific item, then you should not use an array, but a class. Then you can type every property separately.

Comment: What do you expect this code to do if the element *isn't* a number?

Comment: Thank you. But, I know the type of this array is Any. I wanted to know if there is a code that simply parses. Because, this parsing code is very omplexity..

Comment: Oh, I don't thinking class.. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write this instead

```
if((arr[2] as Double) < 40) {
    // ... 
}
```

But note it will throw an exception if it's not actually a `Double`